# jquery conflict with widget page

Tags: plugins, widgets

I'm trying to create a widget plugin that uses a jQuery code to show/hide divs in the widget form based on the selected option of a select drop menu.

The jQuery code I'm trying to implement is working fine everywhere else, but in the widgets page it makes the widgets not working (not expandable or dragable).

This is my code on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fj63g/111/

/* update */

The full plugin code can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/qNc62/

Comment: Your JS code helps might little in thiscase . when widget are non draggable nor expandable (or another symptom is the page stops loading at a certain widget - and hence no sidbars locations) there are 2 reasons 99% of the cases . A) a PHP syntax error (look at the source and see error message) B) A JS conflict/syntax error (you can easily verify with debug tools in your browser) in the other 1% of the cases wp core file pluggable.php is curropt. reinstall wp. In your specific case i can only guess that you need to change all `$` istances to `jQuery` because in wp it loads in `noconflict` mode

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! I don't get any php errors, it's mostly a JS error. And whether I use `$` or `jQuery` it's still not working.

Comment: why are you using an OLD jQuery in fiddle ?

Comment: The latest one, even the one on Google CDN. Anyway, I've uploaded the full plugin code, please give it a try and install it as a plugin.

Comment: It's not about fiddle anyway, it's about wordpress, I'm testing on wordpress is 3.8, and the fiddle is just for the showcase.

Comment: I understand.. but if you are using different jQuery versions for DEV and Production - it can cause compatibility problems ..

Answer (score 0):

used $ within (function($){ /* code */ })(jQuery);

:D

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#kopko').change(function() {
    $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
  });
  $("#kopko").change();
});     
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Still no luck. I'll upload my full plugin code so you can try it.

Comment: yes, pleace ... :D

Comment: Done; http://jsfiddle.net/qNc62/. Upload and test.

Comment: Did you try my plugin yet?

Comment: This only works when at '?widgets-access=on'. But not at '?widgets-access=off' (from the Screen Options)... I guess there's something wrong with jQuery loading.